# Why does "Phone booted!!!" toast message show up on start up?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, toast-notifications

Recently, whenever I power on my phone, a toast appears saying "phone booted!!!". What does that mean? Is it a virus? I haven't installed any apps in a week or so.

[image]

Comment: I've never seen anything like that. Are you running a custom ROM?

Comment: @AlEverett: Yes, my phone is only 4 months old.

Comment: Can you provide some sort of screenshot or picture of the phone showing this message? Are you running Android 4.2? If so, you can long press the notification and see which app is generating the notification.

Comment: The age of your phone has nothing to do with whether you're running a custom ROM. If you are running a custom ROM, which one? Specifically _where_ are you seeing this message?

Comment: @BryanDenny: I'll do that next I time I see the notification message again.

Comment: @AlEverett: I know it has nothing to do with the age of the phone, that was an irrelevant piece of information! I don't understand what you mean by which one. I see the message at the start up screen just when the phone is booted.

Comment: @Gigili: A "notification" is a very specific term for something that appears in your "notification bar". If you're seeing it at the start-up screen it's not a "notification". Please [edit] your question to include the missing information.

Comment: It's shown like delivery reports and other notification messages. I don't know any other term to describe it and there's no missing information.

Comment: Does it appear in the notification bar? Then it's a "notification". Does it rather flash up somewhere else on the screen, and disappear automatically a few seconds later? Then it's a "toast". Does it appear in its own "sub-window", and you have to close it manually? Then it's a "popup". Does it appear full-screen, and you have to press the "back" button? Then it's an "app" (or at least an activity ;)

Comment: @Izzy: TIL. Thank you for your explanation, I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: OK, that's clear now :) Additional questions (please update the details into your question as well): 1) by "turn on" you mean "power on", or really every time you switch on your display? 2) Did this happen from the beginning, or did it just start recently? 3) If recently: Did you install any new app immediately before it started?

Answer (score 1):

Any application that uses RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission can run when the phone boots (i.e. when it is first turned on), in your case to display a toast message.

Try checking the permissions on your (recently installed) apps. Any application that uses "Start on boot" permission is a candidate for your problem.

To further answer your question, I doubt it's a virus, especially if the app in question is installed from official sources. Most likely just a feature developer implemented to notify himself.

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered this message as well. Its one of your applications.

Try to uninstall the last three applications you've installed if you remember their order.

Comment: pls dont use txtspeak, write normal English. Many users here are not native speakers, and some of them already have a hard time without scrambling.